# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Near "SET"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have having trouble with my SQLite syntax. Can anyone give me a hand please? Thank you!:)

Code:

```
public void updateHours(String newDate, String newStart, String Ends, String newNotes,String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL_1 + " = '" + newDate + "' WHERE " + COL_0 + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND SET "+ COL_2 + " = '" + newStart + "' WHERE " + COL_3 + " = '" + Ends + "'" + " AND " + " SET "+ COL_4 + " = '" + newNotes + "'" ;
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Log Cat:

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SET": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: UPDATE ALLWORKHOURS SET DATE = 'Friday, August 12, 29' WHERE ID = '31' AND SET TIMESHIFTSTART = 'cdd' WHERE TIMESHIFTENDS = 'dddd' AND  SET NOTES = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator `AND` is a *logical operator* and you should **not** use it like this:

```
SET column1 = value1 AND column2 = value2 AND ....
```

Also use only 1 `WHERE` clause at the end of the statement.

The correct syntax for an [`UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) statement is:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ................
WHERE condition1 AND/OR condition2..........
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your command syntax.

```
String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL_1 + " = '" + newDate + "' WHERE " + COL_0 + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND SET "+ COL_2 + " = '" + newStart + "' WHERE " + COL_3 + " = '" + Ends + "'" + " AND " + " SET "+ COL_4 + " = '" + newNotes + "'" ;
```

You can't have `SET column = 'asd' WHERE something AND SET column2 = 'asd'`

You should change this to

```
SET column = 'asd' AND column2 = 'asd' WHERE something
```

If those multiple WHERE clauses are different, you should divide that command into many commands

Also, for a better readability to your queries and commands I suggest using [interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your query you cannot have multiple set in the same query. I think this is what you want to do.

```
UPDATE ALLWORKHOURS SET DATE = 'Friday, August 12, 29' AND TIMESHIFTSTART = 'cdd' AND 
NOTES = '  WHERE ID = '31'AND TIMESHIFTENDS = 'dddd'
```